# Defering the loading of javascript in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking to optimise the way in which larger javascript files are loaded in my MVC project. I'm already using bundling and minification but I would really like to only load a few of them AFTER the the HTML and CSS are loaded. I was looking at this kind of approach:

https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html

In this approach the script tags are injected into using javascript in the load/onload event after the body is loaded. My problem is that I would like to use along side the bundling and minification offered by the framework and I haven't found a good way to do that.

I'l just wondering if anybody has successfully used this approach with MVC projects and if there might already be a library (on Nuget or otherwise) to facilitate this.

EDITED: Here is my current solution, but I'm not sure I like it.

Since the Bundling framework can return a single script tag or a list of them depending on whether you're running in debug or not we need to extract the source values for those tags. To do this I created a static helper.

```
public static string ExtactFromScriptBundle(string aBundle)
    {
        List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();

        var jQueryString = Scripts.Render(aBundle).ToHtmlString();

        var reg = new Regex("\".*?\"");

        var matches = reg.Matches(jQueryString);
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            returnValue.Add(match.ToString().Replace("\"", ""));
        }

        return Json.Encode(returnValue);
    }
```

Than from _layout.cshtml you cound insert a block like the following right before the  tag:

```
<script>
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
     createScripElementsFromArray(@Html.Raw(ScriptHelper.ExtactFromScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")));
createScripElementsFromArray(@Html.Raw(ScriptHelper.ExtactFromScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap")));
    }

    function createScripElementsFromArray(fileNameList) {
        var arrayLength = fileNameList.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            createScripElement(fileNameList[i]);
        }
    }

    function createScripElement(fileName) {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        console.log(fileName + " was loaded");
    }

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

It's a bit a hack in my opinion since I'm rendering the bundles just to parse the output, but I guess I could also cache those outputs to further optimize the page rendering.

Answer (score 4):

By [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), the best solution is to use the *defer* attribute ...

```
<script src='myJavaScriptFile.js' defer></script>
```

It is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=defer).

If you want to use it in ASP.NET MVC, then you'll do this:

Create a new Razor command like so:

```
public static class Scripts
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderDeferred(params string[] paths)
    {
        return Scripts.RenderFormat(@"<script src='{0}' defer></script>", paths);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
@Scripts.RenderDeferred("~/myBundle/myJavaScriptBundle")
```

Comment: Assuming I'm loading each file myself, but also want to use the bundling and minification framework to optimize the files.

Comment: Alright then, @daoom, how about now?  See my updated answer.

Comment: My problem is that while the solution seems elegant the implementation of the defer keyword varies from browser to browser and the order in which the scripts will be loaded and executed isn't completely deterministic. Using defer, if script B depends on script A and both are loaded with defer, even though you place one before the other you can't guarantee that they will always load and execute in order.

Comment: I think you're thinking of 'async'. Async order is non-deterministic.  Defer will always run in the order you list just ... well ... later.  Besides, you could control edge cases by putting the ones where order is important in the head without defer and the normal ones at the end.  All this adheres to the Principle of Least Astonishment when other devs read your code.  Just saying ...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use jquery to load external scripts. You'd have an initial dependency on jquery itself but jquery is very light weight.

You'd then have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //At this point, the HTML/CSS has already been loaded and rendered.

    //load external scripts
    $.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
       console.log( data ); // Data returned
       console.log( textStatus ); // Success
       console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
       console.log( "Load was performed." );
    });

});
```

Jquery doc: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it doesn't leverage the bundling/minification framework to compress test.js.